# Linking IOKit with Theos

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I'm attempting to link with IOKit using Theos, but I'm getting linker errors.

I've added the following to my makefile:

`xxx_PRIVATE_FRAMEWORKS = IOKit`

Yet the linker emits errors for all functions from IOKit, such as:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "IOHIDEventGetType(void*)", referenced from:
      handle_event(void*, void*, void*, void*) in Tweak.xm.7c83e24c.o
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this wasn't really a linking issue. My declaration of the private IOHID* functions just needed to be surrounded with extern "C".